# Workflow LockProcess AEM - Not locking the asset/page

Tags: java, aem

I have a custom workflow for which the first step is default AEM "LockProcess". But somehow the asset/page not getting locked.

I have initiated the workflow as an admin and I'm using AEM 6.2

```
27.07.2017 13:16:09.994 *INFO* [JobHandler: 
/etc/workflow/instances/server0/2017-07-25/workflow_name:/content/project/en-
us/test-general] com.day.cq.workflow.impl.process.LockProcess Locking is not 
currently enabled.  This is a No-Op
```

[image: Workflow History]
The same happens for "UnlockProcess".

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable locking of the payload in the "Day CQ Workflow Service" configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments from [Adobe Forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2356571), I found there is a property 
**cq.workflow.service.allow.locking** that should be enabled in CQWorkflowService.

Unfortunately, I could not find CQWorkflowService in http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr.

Digging further I found this website [Missing Service](http://www.aemstuff.com/osgi/aem62.html) that list all missing the hyperlinks for factory service and components of AEM 6.2.

Finally, I was able to initiate the default Lockprocess.